# cant open oracle enterpise manager on oracle database 21c

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have problem with login in enterprise manager. I have windows 10 Education.Database successfully installed but still unable to log into http.

Po wydaniu polecenia lsnrctl:

```
lsnrctl status | findstr HOST
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-M3MIGG3)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-M3MIGG3)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-M3MIGG3)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\APEX\APEX\DB\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-M3MIGG3)(PORT=9000))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
```

when i try to connect in: localhost:9000 I need to enter a username and password, but neither match, I tried to create a user in the database as well, but it also doesn't work

Query select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport() looks like:

```
SQL> select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport() from dual;

DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.GETHTTPSPORT()
------------------------------
                          5500
```

Can someone help me what should i do? And what could be the problem?

Comment: Use port 5500, not 9000.

Comment: on port 5500 i have nothing just: This website is down, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the credentials are not working

Comment: #oracle #entreprise_manager

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).